# import dependencies from another module

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I think I am missing some point in how dependencies management works in gradle.
Let's say I have the following project structure:

```
project
---api
------api-commons
------api-v1
------api-v2
------api-v3
```

where all `api*` directories are modules. All `api-v*` need a particular dependency (let's say `common-dependency`).

My aim would be to import it in `api-commons build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'common-dependency'
}
```

while in the `build.gradle` files of the other modules `api-v*` put:

```
dependencies{
   implementation project(':api:api-commons')
}
```

I would expect this to work but it doesn't. The code in the `api-v*` modules simply acts like the dependency is not declared. Indeed, if I import the dependency in the single modules, the code works as expected.

Am I doing a wrong assumption? Doesn't the dependency inheritance work like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declaring a dependency in the `implementation` configuration conceptually means it is internal to the module (it is used in the implementation but not part of the public API). Such a dependency will not be exposed to the compile classpath of consumers, though it will still be on the runtime classpath.

An advantage of this way of modelling dependencies is that you do not need to recompile consuming projects if an implementation dependency changes. Another is that by encapsulating them, it is less likely that a consumer will start depending on them directly and then breaking if you change them.

If you want to expose the dependency to consumers, you have to declare it as part of the API for the module. You do that by applying the `java-library` plugin and using the `api` configuration.

Example:

```java
// api-commons/build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
   api 'common-dependency'
}
```

Read more about it in the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

Answer (score 0):

Let say, I have to moved below common code(*.java files) from below 2 service/modules to sharedprocessing-data which is present inside shared-libraries service/modules :

- abc-service
- xyz-servcie

  ```
  Address.java
  Employee.java
  Department.java
  Vaccation.java
  Name.java
  City.java
  Order.java
  ```

**Steps0:**

In shared- service/modules folder create additional module inside existing shared-libraries module

Name it as **sharedprocessing-data**

**Steps1:**

Move(refactor) common code inside this module

**Steps2:**

In parent folder (root)  update **settings.gradle** file

```
rootProject.name = "root"
include 'abc-service'
include 'xyz-service'
include 'shared-libraries:sharedprocessing-data'
```

**Step3:**

In each of abc-service and xyz-flow service modules, update build.gradle file

```
 dependencies
 { 
   implementation project(':shared-libraries:sharedprocessing-data') 
 }
```